# How can I verify if the user is logged in? I need to show stuff only if users are loged in.This is the code Im using

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```php
@if(auth()->user()->isAdmin())

content

@endif


@if(auth()->user()->isNormal())

content 

@endif
```

and then if the user is not logged in i get this error:

Call to a member function `isAdmin()` on `null` (path to user.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can change your code like shown below

@auth
  content if user is logged in
@endauth


@guest
  content if user is not logged in 
@endguest
```

Answer (score 2):

What this error, `Call to a member function isAdmin() on null`, tells you is that there was no object attached to whatever you called the function from. In this case it is the authenticated user. That means that there was no authenticated user when you called the `isAdmin()`.

You can avoid it by first checking if the user is logged in. @Alberto gives you different options of doing it. Additionally, you could adjust your `if` statements like so:

```
@if( auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin() )
...
@if( auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isNormal() )
```

Here, the first condition checks if there is an authenticated user, and the second condition will only be checked if the first statement returned `true`.

On a side note, you could use `Policies` or/and `Gate` to achieve more robust authorisation logic.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#control-structures), there is a `@auth ... @endauth` directive that check if the user is logged in (same thing done by `@if (Auth::check())`), and as opposite there is `@guest ... @endguest` to check if is not logged in (same thing done by `@if (!Auth::check())`).